# Some users can have a fixed amount of additional fields, EAV or not?

Tags: mysql, database-design, eav, subtypes

Say I have to store data about two different types of person *roles* or *occupations*, i.e., `Consumers` and `Merchants`, and both types of roles share a single base table called `User`.

In this respect, `Merchants` need to have a few additional fields, e.g., `CompanyName`, `CompanyDescription`.

What is the most efficient way to design a database for these specifications?

1. Have extra columns on the `User` table.
2. Have an extra table called `MerchantData` which has a `UserId` FOREIGN KEY.
3. Have a `UserMeta` EAV table which allows any amount of additional values.

I am currently leaning towards option 2, as the additional fields are fixed. Are there any down sides that I am not seeing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since *Consumers* and *Merchants* share some common data as **Users** they should be in a single base table, as you have already mentioned.

An **EAV** implementation can be successful under some well planned and controlled use.  But I see nothing in your question that would imply that an **EAV** solution is the right answer.

In fact, as you move further in your development you might find that not only do *Merchants* have some additional attributes, but so do *Consumers*.  If so, you might want a simple **Supertype-Subtype** model.

That would give you 3 tables that are related as shown below:

> ```
>                USERS (contains common information)
>                  |
>                  |
>      ____________|_____________
>      |                        |
>      | (details specific to   | 
>      |       a subtype)       |
> Consumers                Merchants
> ```

If this works for you, much of the time you would only access the *Users* table, but when you needed additional information for a *Consumer* or a *Merchant* you would like to those details as well.

This is a pretty simple approach and avoids unneeded duplication of data.

For a perspective on EAV implementations, you might look at Aaron Bertrand's post, which explains the advantages and the limitations.

- https://sqlblog.org/2009/11/19/what-is-so-bad-about-eav-anyway

Note that in this case it was rapidly changing requirements which made the EAV decision a good choice.

Comment: Does this still apply if a user can be a consumer and a merchant at the same time?

Comment: Yes, if the unique information placed in the proper subtype, then all should be clear.

Comment: If you go with the three table solution, you may also be interested in a technique called shared primary key.  In this technique, the Id field in Consumers and Merchants is a copy of the Id field in Users, and therefore a foreign key reference to it.  This means that a foreign key in some fourth table can point to the users table and also the consumers table, the merchants table, or both.

Comment: If you want to do some more reading, look up what Martin Fowler refers to as Class Table Inheritance.

Comment: @WalterMitty - I agree that it is useful to use the SuperType ID for  the SubType IDs.

Answer (score 0):

I would go ahead with the EAV implementation but would further decorate the attributes with an additional table (AttributeGroup), which could be quite handy for reporting and segregation purpose, something like this:

`Table name: AttributeGroup`

```
Id        Name
==        ==========
1         Consumer
2         Merchant
3         Something else
```

Then, you can have one more One-to-many relational table with Attributes. Just explaining the concept, but if you need me to provide an example, then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, here is my more modern advice here, are you going to query on the *extra* fields,

- if so, consider normalization.
- if not, save yourself the time and use a JSON. It's an integral part of SQL:2016.

Currently, MySQL provides a Binary JSON type. MariaDB has acknowledged one of the many errors in their way, and they're moving to implement a binary JSON field. This *largely* but not entirely marks the death of EAVs, the only time I would consider an EAV currently is if the attributes themselves were the subject of a query, *and* they were only key-value pairs.

And, that's not to say that JSON won't trump EAVs more in the future. Under many workloads PostgreSQLs GiST can provide competitive querying or even beat EAV performance. It's only a matter of decades before MySQL provides the same functionality.